# recording co-ordinates of the pointer in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to move the pointer with the help of arrow keys and I want to record the coordinates at every position in x2,y2? The initial position of the pointer is 0,0

Answer (score 0):

To simply use the pointer location, you can use the following functions to get and set the pointer location on screen.

```
location = get(0,'PointerLocation')
set(0,'PointerLocation',[0,0]);
```

However, I would particularly recommend doing this unless really necessary because it may provide a bad user experience. People do not like the computer moving a mouse on them, at least I do not.

Read [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rootobject_props.html) on the various "root" properties that can be used in MATLAB.

Note: setting the pointer location is not possible on a Mac OS

**UPDATE**

If you want to be able to control your cursor with the arrow keys, you need to first create a figure and then attach a keylistener to it. This key listener, when triggered, will call a separate function that can move the mouse.

**Creating Listener**

```
h_fig = figure;
set(h_fig,'KeyPressFcn',@(h_obj,evt) moveCursor(evt.Key));
```

This wlil make sure that every time a key is pressed while the figure is active, it will pass to a function you will call `moveCursor`. The move cursor function is in a separate file and is called of course `moveCursor.m` and will look as follows

**moveCursor.m**

```
function moveCursor(key)
    numPixels = 100;
    loc = get(0,'PointerLocation');
    if strcmpi(key,'uparrow')
        loc(2) = loc(2)+numPixels;
    elseif strcmpi(key,'downarrow')
        loc(2) = loc(2)-numPixels;
    elseif strcmpi(key,'leftarrow')
        loc(1) = loc(1)-numPixels;
    elseif strcmpi(key,'rightarrow')
        loc(1) = loc(1)+numPixels;
    end
    set(0,'PointerLocation',loc);
end
```

Now you can simply run the listener commands to launch the window, press the arrow keys, and it should move your cursor the amount of pixels specified in `moveCursor.m`, in this case 100 pixels.

I still would not particularly recommend this behavior but know it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I want to use arrow keys to move the pointer.

Comment: You would need to add a listener for the arrow keys, attach that to a figure, and then have a function that is called any time a button is pressed. I will edit my answer to include this.

Comment: Thank you the reply. This is working with the figure. But how to make it work on psychtoolbox. I have a screen on psychtoolbox. What to assign to h_fig

Comment: assuming you are using the `openWindow` command to create this window, it should return a pointer to that window. This should be the same as your figure handle. I am not completely sure because I have not used `psychtoolbox` before but I would just read through the documentation on how to get a figure handle. [Screen Documentation](http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/Screen)